# Can I create an exe on Linux?

Tags: launch4j

I would like to package a Java application into a `.exe` file using launch4j.

My build server is a Linux based operating system. Is it possible to build the `.exe` on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I have done it with Jenkins on a debian system. You might get some problems with missing libs. So you have to install them on your build server.

See: https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin#faq

```
Q: Can I use Launch4j on 64bit OS?

A: Yes but you will have to install these libs to avoid problems:

    lib32z1
    lib32ncurses5
    lib32bz2-1.0 ( (has been ia32-libs in older Ubuntu versions)
    zlib.i686
    ncurses-libs.i686
    bzip2-libs.i686
```

In my case for debian I've installed the following packages:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev
apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5
```